# Upgrading an App Inventor app in Play Store

Tags: app-inventor

I have a simple question (I hope), Let's say I make an app in A.I. and upload it to Play Store. Now I want to upgrade it. Do I have to make the changes in A.I. then redownload it and then reupload it with the same name, or what is the process?

Thank You!!!

Comment: Okay, I did a little research and found he answer online, answered by Taifan, I am quoting it: "yes, see also here http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/apps-google-play.html
Taifun"

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to your "Screen1" , there on the sidebar on the right side, you'll see 
-version name
-version code
you have to update version name (natural nos. 1,2,3...) and version code (1.1, 1.5, 3.2 etc.)
if version code and name are higher than previous, then the play store will accept you update. and yes, you need to "packeage for phone and download to this computer" every time you wanna launch an update.